# Kali Encrypted Persistence opens wrong device (HDD instead of USB)

Tags: linux, encryption, kali-linux, disk-encryption, luks

I have created the encrypted live USB as per Kali documentation. I have set up encrypted persistence with cryptsetup as mentioned in the documentation. I've verified that I'm able access the partition(**/dev/sdc2**) with "cryptsetup luksOpen".

On my computer, I have a primary linux installation on **/dev/sda2 (HDD)** which is also encrypted LUKS setup.

When I boot via USB and select "Live system with encrypted persistence", Kali wants to open **/dev/sda2 (on HDD) and not /dev/sdc2 (USB drive)** as I need it to.

What can be done so that Kali only asks to decrypt **/dev/sdc2** as persistence partition?

Comment: When you boot a live session the USB media is `sda`.

Comment: @MichaelBay The hard drive used to always be sda, but the last few years when I boot (live) the drive letters randomly change order sometimes, maybe a kernel change a while ago or something. Anyway @ machy, don't use device letters, use UUID instead. I don't know how kali does it's persistence, but search for a UUID or maybe even partition label option

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I don't have a better solution except to recommend to enter an incorrect password, and when asked if you want to re-try, to enter "n". For me, Kali used the next encrypted partition available, which was the one on the USB drive.